# Web & Mobile Analytics emails conversion trackings

Tags: marketing-cloud

I want to know how many conversions have been made since the emails.
If we compare with Google Analytics, it would be how much conversion I have on my UTM campaigns.

Logically, it should go up in the table email conversion tracking, so the probleme is nothing happen.

The tracking on the links are well implemented. It's an email rattrapeur basket so it's clear that we track the links ...

And if I look with Google Analytics, I see conversions up from that mail, so it's on there are and that users are identified is always

Can you help me please to find out where is the problem and why i can't have any result

Thank you 
Ouassim

Comment: Question unclear! Did you add "conversion=true" to the link in your email ? And or you adding any parameters like JobID, SubID to the link ? or Do you have web analytics connector enabled in your account ? Please post your link, Landing page and Conversion page code

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to this question (I'm also working on this issue) :

On click on the mail link, redirected to : landing.php?j=35692&sfmc_sub=40341287&l=30_HTML&u=1970696&mid=10959617&jb=1

Code of the landing page :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Conversion page</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://10959617.collect.igodigital.com/collect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

_etmc.push(["setOrgId", "10959617"]);
_etmc.push(["trackPageView", { "item" : "Hotel_Test" }]);    


});
</script>


</head>

<body>
Landing Page<br/>
<br/>
<a href="conversion.php">conversion</a>

</body> 
</html>
```

Code of the conversion page :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Conversion page</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://10959617.collect.igodigital.com/collect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
_etmc.push(["setOrgId", "10959617"]);
_etmc.push(["trackPageView"]);
   _etmc.push(["trackConversion", { "cart": [
    {"item" : "Hotel_Test", "quantity":  "1" , "price" : "99" ,
            "unique_id" : "hotel_test" } ]

   }]); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
Purchase Page
</body> 
</html>
```